# Как объединить несколько вариантов проверки в одно сравнение в if, Python?

Tags: python

не знаю можно ли объединить несколько условий в одно
Пример:

```
if x==2 or x==3 or x==4 ....
```

Я хочу это как-то покороче записать

---

Это можно сделать так:

```py
if s in (2,3,4)
```

python будет сравнивать переменную "s" с числами 2,3,4.

Comment: `if x in (2,3,4): ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете проверит есть х в списке нужных значений :

```
allowed_list = [2,3,4,5]
if x in allowed_list:
    print(x)
```

Comment: А как можно одно число сравнить с несколькими другими?

Comment: @Flashdim код в ответе именно это и делает

Comment: if s1>s2 and s1>s3 and s1>s4 - вот так например

Comment: @Flashdim тут нужно просто воспользоваться правилом "больше большего"

Comment: @Flashdim да, верно